# compare any two moments of the 10 moments of time

Tags: python, list, range

Im trying to write a program that has a data of n = 10 which is the moments of time of one day, these are: hours (values from 0
to 23), minutes (from 0 to 59) and seconds (from 0 to 59). Write a program that
compares any two moments of time (determines which of the moments occurred in
given day earlier). So in simpler words I want to have 10 random moments with hours minutes and seconds, hours can't be repeating so for example lets say [14:34;24, 16:25:26...... and so on for 10 times, so if I want to take lets say the first number from the list and the 2nd from the list so that would be (14:34;24) and (16:25:26) and to see which one happened earlier between the 2. was able to state the numbers but not sure how to do the comparision and how to state it all.

```
import random
hours = (random.randint(0,23) for i in range (10))
minutes = (random.randint(0,59) for i in range (10))
seconds = (random.randint(0,59) for i in range (10))
num_of_H=list(zip(hours,minutes))
num_of_M=list(zip(hours,minutes))
print(dict(num_of_H))
nums=(i for i in range(10))
res=dict(zip(nums,num_of_H))
print(res)
while True:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking advantage of the fact that `tuples` are first sorted based on first index, then second index, then third index and so on...

```py
import random

n = 10
moments = []
hours_tracker = set() # for requirement "hours can't be repeating"
for _ in range(n):
    hours = random.randint(0, 23)
    while hours in hours_tracker:
        hours = random.randint(0, 23)
    hours_tracker.add(hours)

    minutes = random.randint(0, 59)
    seconds = random.randint(0, 59)
    moments.append((hours, minutes, seconds)) # appending a tuple to list

sorted_moments = sorted(moments)
```

Output

```py
>>> print(moments)
>>> [(6, 14, 39), (16, 4, 22), (14, 31, 3), (9, 27, 56), (17, 1, 33), (15, 10, 42), (7, 53, 47), (18, 11, 6), (8, 22, 45), (12, 32, 42)]

>>> print(sorted_moments)
>>> [(6, 14, 39), (7, 53, 47), (8, 22, 45), (9, 27, 56), (12, 32, 42), (14, 31, 3), (15, 10, 42), (16, 4, 22), (17, 1, 33), (18, 11, 6)]
```

Now you can use the sorted moments in any way or format you want.

Comment: Although I got the idea but the code did not work out Niels Borie gave me and idea and I will merge both of your ideas together but im stuck now on the how to find which one comes first im thinking about to use if loop to find the smaller number with the format H m s if H are the same then go to m and if they are the same go to seconds and if they are both the same then I am the unluckiest man alive

Comment: What part of this code is not working? And the first item in ```sorted_moments``` is the moment that came first, and 2nd item is the moment that came second and so on.

Comment: well print(moments) is an invalid syntax I'm not sure if i am blind because i changed it and it still did not work i tried what you told me in the last message and still nothing same message am I not seeing something clear ?

Comment: don't just copy paste the code I gave, remove ```>>>``` and the space between ```>>>``` and ```print()```.

Comment: ofc i removed the signs but it still says error

Comment: which line gives error? Can you paste the line as it is in your editor?

Comment: Never mind found the problem the file is corrupted and does not see python at all I just made a file and now it sees it all, i saw the problem when i saw the print the same color as the numbers

Comment: thank you this solved the issue with identifying the numbers and their format, but i didnt want for the list  to be assorted in order rather so i can chose which index I want to take and from the two I chose to find which index happened earlier than the other.

Comment: In that case, you can remove ```sorted_moments = sorted(moments)``` and simply use ```if (index of your choice) < (index of your choice)``` for items in ```moments```.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library, it will help you manipulate dates in Python.

A datetime object needs additional information to be built (year, month, day), then you can generate the times of day you want with your code.

If we go back to your code, by first building a reference date (I took the current date, you can put what you want), you can generate your list of dates like that.

```
import random
import datetime

base_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
dts = [base_datetime.replace(hour=random.randint(0, 23), minute=random.randint(0, 59), second=random.randint(0, 59)) for i in range(10)]
```

And print it (to make it look better during printing, you can manipulate the display format):

```
print([dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S') for dt in dts])
# an example of a result :
# return : ['00:29:03', '22:41:51', '00:04:06', '15:56:38', '03:41:36', '18:15:40', '19:22:33', '18:19:33', '18:39:19', '05:38:26']
```

Now you can compare each element of your list with the usual python operators (<,>,!= ... ).

```
print(dts[0] < dts[1])
# from the previous example : '00:29:03' < '22:41:51'
# return: True
```

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thank you for the plan I will merge your and BhusalC_Bipin ideas together but im stuck now on the how to find which one comes first im thinking about to use if loop to find the smaller number with the format H m s if H are the same then go to m and if they are the same go to seconds im just not anderstanding much about your last point about to compare each element in the list

Comment: The last comment was there if you ever wanted to make peer to peer comparisons of your items. If you just want an ordered list, `sorted(dts)` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help I was able to merge all of your ideas and was able to come up with this, i guess it was hard for me to explain what i had in mind but here is what I meant.
import random

```
n = 10
moments = []
hours_tracker = set()
for _ in range(n):
    hours = random.randint(0, 23)
    #if you want hours to possibly repeat comment out while loop:
    while hours in hours_tracker:
        hours = random.randint(0, 23)
    hours_tracker.add(hours)

    minutes = random.randint(0, 59)
    seconds = random.randint(0, 59)
    moments.append((hours, minutes, seconds))

for i in range(len(moments)):
   print(str(i) + ": " + str(moments[i]))

print()

t1 = int(input("What first time would you like to select? "))
t2 = int(input("What second time would you like to select? "))

#CHECKING FOR HOURS
if ((moments[t1])[0] < (moments[t2])[0]):
  print(str(moments[t1]) + " occurred before " + str(moments[t2]))
elif ((moments[t1])[0] > (moments[t2])[0]):
  print(str(moments[t2]) + " occurred before " + str(moments[t1]))
```